# Installing magento, get database connection error.

Tags: mysql, database, magento

I am trying to install magento onto my webhost, during install i get "database connection error" i have input all the values correctly (have contacted my webhost to be sure as I am stumped at this point) they said to refer to magento forums for extra support. I cannot find a fix. Any ideas / help would be MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this script which tests your connection and reports the actual MySQL error. It might be useful to determine whether the credentials you were given will work, or which part of the process is failing. Since you are using it on a remote webhost I recommend you hard-code the database username and password to avoid passing them in clear over the open Internet.

(Note: Not my own work - script comes from webune.com)

```
<?php
###################################### C O P Y R I G H T S ####################################
# THIS SCRIPT IS DISTRIBUTED BY WEBUNE.COM UNDER LICENSE UNDER THE GPL RULES
# PLEASE DO NOT REMOVE THIS MESSAGE IN SUPPORT OF OUR HARD WORK TO CONTINUE TO PROVIDE FREE SUPPORT
###############################################################################################
# OK, HERE WE GO
# Use this varialble if you are using an installation script
$step = $_GET['step'];
if (!$step) {
    $page_title = 'Form';
}
else{
    $page_title = 'Test MySQL step '.$step;
}
############## BEGIN FUNCTIONS ##############################
# FUNCTION TO TEST USERNAME AND PASSWORD IN MYSQL HOST
function db_connect($server, $username, $password, $link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link, $db_error;
    $db_error = false;
    if (!$server) {
        $db_error = 'No Server selected.';
        return false;
    }
    $$link = @mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or $db_error = mysql_error();
    return $$link;
}
# FUNCTION TO SELECT DATABASE ACCESS
function db_select_db($database) {
    echo mysql_error();
    return mysql_select_db($database);
}
# FUNCTION TO TEST DATABASE ACCESS
function db_test_create_db_permission($database) {
    global $db_error;
    $db_created = false;
    $db_error = false;
    if (!$database) {
        $db_error = 'No Database selected.';
        return false;
    }
    if ($db_error) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (!@db_select_db($database)) {
            $db_error = mysql_error();
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    return true;
    }
}

function step1 ($error) {
    echo '<h1 style="color:#FF0000">'.$error.'</h1><hr>';
?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?step=2">
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td><div align="right">mysql hostname:</div></td>
<td><input name="server" type="text" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['server']; ?>">
(usually &quot;localhost&quot; or enter IP Address of MySQL Server)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">mysql username:</div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['username']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">mysql username password:</div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['password']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">mysql database name:</div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="database" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['database']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Webune MYSQL TEST - <?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php echo $page_title; ?></h1>
<?php
############## END FUNCTIONS ##############################
switch ($step) {
    case '2':
        if ($_REQUEST['server']) {
    $db = array();
    $db['DB_SERVER'] = trim(stripslashes($_REQUEST['server']));
    $db['DB_SERVER_USERNAME'] = trim(stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']));
    $db['DB_SERVER_PASSWORD'] = trim(stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']));
    $db['DB_DATABASE'] = trim(stripslashes($_REQUEST['database']));
    $db_error = false;
    db_connect($db['DB_SERVER'], $db['DB_SERVER_USERNAME'], $db['DB_SERVER_PASSWORD']);
    if ($db_error == false) {
        if (!db_test_create_db_permission($db['DB_DATABASE'])) {
            $error = $db_error;
        }
    } else {
        $error = $db_error;
    }
    if ($db_error != false) {
        $error = "failed";
        echo step1($db_error);
    } else {
        echo '<h1 style="color:green">Congratulations!</h1>
        Connected Successfuly to datbase <strong>
        <a href="http://www.webune.com/forums/how-to-test-mysql-database-connection.html">Continue &gt;&gt; </a></strong>';
    }
        } else {
            $error = "ERROR: please provide a hostanme";
            echo step1($error);
        }
    break;

    default:
    echo step1('Step 1');
    break;
}
?>
<div align="center">
<img src="http://www.webune.com/images/headers/default_logo.jpg">
</div>
<div align="center">
Script Courtesy of
<a href="http://www.webune.com">Webune PHP/Mysql Hosting</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where do i put this? as a file on the host?

Comment: @user1937185 Yes. You would upload this script to your web hosting space in the same location as your Magento installation. And then run it via your browser.

Comment: it connects successfully does that mean its something wrong with the magento side?

Comment: it's working now looks like the webhost fixed mysql permissions or something, waiting for a reply. thank you for your help

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this issue by creating database manually using phpMyAdmin before submitting database settings.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to PhpMyAdmin
2. Create a database (e.g. Magento-Madabase)
3. Edit the properties of the database and add access to a new user (e.g. Magento-User@localhost with a password)
4. Install Magento. When it asks for a database type Magento-Database and when it asks for user and password chose Magento-User and the set password.

... installation will continue without problems !

Comment: I just added a new user in PHPMyadmin with "localhost" privileges and no password, et voila.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have created a database name with the value you specified in the database name textfield

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of possible reasons for this error, but if your database name, username and password are all correct, and assuming your database is on the same host, you could try swapping the hostname and IP address:

That is, if you are currently trying "localhost" as your hostname, try "127.0.0.1" instead. If you are already trying "127.0.0.1", try "localhost".

Comment: Thanks, i'm not using localhost i'm using a hostname provided by the webhost. Tried it anyway and still no joy. Really not sure how to proceed. Thank you for your help =)

Answer (score 1):

at time of magento installation when you entering username and password , type in the username field  'root' instead of your own username and password field must be blank. 
"this solution is work successfully".........

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to  **xampp\php\php.ini**  and remove the **";"** sign before **"extension=php_curl.dll"**

2 ) just go to following location and replace the code :

**file location : app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml**

**find code :** `<pdo_mysql>`

and

**replace with :**

```
<pdo_mysql> 1 </pdo_mysql>
```

Comment: On Second point:  folder is not found on given loaction "app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml"

Answer (score 0):

- Go to `app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Db.php`
- Find the `checkDatabase($data)` function
- At the end of this function, there is the following code:

  ```
  Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('install')->__('Database connection error.'));
  ```
- Change it to the following:

  ```
  Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('install')->__($e->getMessage()));
  ```
- Go to your browser, where you are installing Magento, click the `Continue` button
- Now, you should be able to see some proper error message

In my case, I got the following error message:

> Database server does not support the InnoDB storage engine.

So, to solve this, I commented the InnoDB check in the same `checkDatabase` function.

```
// check InnoDB support
/*if (!isset($variables['have_innodb']) || $variables['have_innodb'] != 'YES') {
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('install')->__('Database server does not support the InnoDB storage engine.'));
}*/
```

After that, I was able to install Magento.