# Magento installation database connection error

Tags: database, magento, xampp

I've created a database with a user "jack". I'm doing this through xampp locally. 
https://puu.sh/xi7wh/e3046fd320.png

I'm trying to install magento with this connection:

https://puu.sh/xi7AX/98460dd7c0.png

But I get "database connection error". I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Confirm that database ( level_mag ) name created in phpmyadmin . Still problem showing then try to set hostname as localhost and then try. more details https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_installation.htm

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check your database user name and password. Before you proceed to this step, you should have already set up the database in MySQL. You need to create a user and grant access privileges to that user.

Then check your MySQL server configuration. The default port number is 3306. However, your system admin might change it to something else. Or if you are using software packages such as MAMP/WAMP, the port number may be set to something other than 3306. In these cases, you need to explicitly put the port number in the Host field.

If all these are correct and you still have database connection error, you can try to use root account to access the database. If root works out, that means there are problems with the privileges in your MySQL settings. Although it is not recommended to use root account for future production deployment as it adds security risks to the server.

More information visit following URLS :-
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84782/database-connection-error-magento-installation
[Installing magento, get database connection error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674195/installing-magento-get-database-connection-error)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use hostname as 127.0.0.1 alongwith port no. if changed and the same in the URL as well

Answer (score 0):

first you have to check the configuration.and then check the port number specified.if it is the default one, simply write the host name as localhost or other you assign else you have to specify the hostname with its port number.